# error: expected ‘}’ at end of input

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
#include <libubuntuone-1.0/u1-music-store.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-authentication.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-credentials.h>
#include <libsyncdaemon-1.0/libsyncdaemon/syncdaemon-daemon.h>

static void
get_credentials (U1MusicStore *music_store,
                                 gchar **oauth_consumer_token,
                                 gchar **oauth_consumer_secret,
                                 gchar **oauth_token,
                                 gchar **oauth_token_secret)
{
    SyncdaemonCredentials *credentials;
    *oauth_consumer_token = *oauth_consumer_secret = *oauth_token = *oauth_token_secret = NULL;

    *oauth_consumer_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_key (credentials));
    *oauth_consumer_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_consumer_secret (credentials));
    *oauth_token = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token (credentials));
    *oauth_consumer_secret = g_strdup (syncdaemon_credentials_get_token_secret (credentials));
}

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

and the only thing preventing it from compiling is the error message specified in the title of this question. The problem line has been identified as the closing brace of the `main` function, but that obviously isn't the case, and I can't see where else I could have missed out any parentheses. Can anyone else spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I haven't read all the above code, but check your header files too. Are you sure they are all OK?

Comment: Does it compile if you comment out the body of `get_credentials()`? Actually go a step further and comment out everything except for the `#include headers`. The headers should  compile by themselves or there might be a stray '{' somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: @Brian, thanks, I'll check them now. @Victor, no, it still fails. I'm going to check the header files. I didn't check them because they weren't written by me and are already being used in production code so I just assumed they would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of such errors it is good idea to localize error. You can do it simply, by commenting blocks of code.

In this example you can comment body `get_credentials` function and check what will happen.

Also good idea to paste empty line at the end of source code file.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe some of the included headers has mismatched braces.

Maybe the compiler is bad at handling files with non-empty last line, and there is such line in some of the files.

Try commenting out as much as you can (especially all includes) to make it compile, and then putting code back in until you localize the problem.